# Implementing a LongPress progress notification in Windows Phone 7

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, touch

How can I monitor the progress of a long press on a StackPanel with a Silverlight Toolkit context menu attached?

I have a LongListSelector control. An item's template has a StackPanel with:

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Upload" />
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

context menu attached in a standard manner. Whenever a user presses and holds the stackpanel, a context menu appears within the next few seconds.

I want a user to be notified, that the countdown for a context menu pop up is on, by showing them a progress bar on top in a stack panel. An example can be seen here:

[image]

More presentative in a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=radnJgI88dA

Can I hook-in to the Press progress to implement it with a Silverlight Toolkit Context Menu? If not, how can I achieve this?

I know that I just need to be Setting a ProgessBar value, but how can I get the events of a progress to be fired? Is starting a count-up with my own timer is the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event in `ContextMenu` control. You can implement it yourself by handling touch events (such MouseLeftButtonDown, etc.) and a `DispatcherTimer` to measure elapsed time.

Also, `Silverlight Toolkit` is an open source library, so you can modify `ContextMenu` control to have such behavior on all attached `ContextMenu` where you need it.

UPD:

I created simple animation. Result is like on the video

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="progress">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="progressBar">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="100"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="progressBar">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

And there is a logic for manage this animation. `Rectangle` is a parent of `ContextMenu`

```
    private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Begin();
    }

    private void LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: As of the first part of your answer - yes, I can implement it myself by starting the countup after the mouse event is fired. But after looking into a sources of a ContextMenu, I realized that it comes into play only after the Hold event of a UIElement is fired, so there is no relation between the control and the countdown before the Hold event, which is exactly where I need to hook into. Thanks anyway. I will wait for a more concrete answer for a bit, and if none arrives, we'll consider "do it yourself" approach as the most probable solution.

Comment: A "code-enabled" version of an answer worked just fine. Thank you.